# Renaming Files with "Invalid Characters"

Tags: arrays, shell, onedrive

I have a script that removes invalid characters from files due to one drive restrictions.  It works except for file that have * { } in them. I have used the * { } but that is not working (ignores those files).   Script is below.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

`````
#Renames FOLDERS with space at the end
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find -d . -name "* ")
do
 target_name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')
 if [ "$file" != "$target_name" ]; then
     if [ -e $target_name ]; then
         echo "WARNING: $target_name already exists, file not renamed"
     else
         echo "Move $file to $target_name"
         mv "$file" "$target_name"
     fi
 fi
done

#end Folder rename

#Renames FILES

declare -a arrayGrep=(\? \* \, \# \; \: \& \@ \+ \< \> \% \$ \~ \% \: \< \> )
echo "array: ${arrayGrep[@]}"
for  i in "${arrayGrep[@]}"
do
       for file in $(find .  | grep $i )
       do
               target_name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/\'$i'/-/g' )
               if [ "$file" != "$target_name" ]; then
                 if [ -e $target_name ]; then
                       echo "WARNING: $target_name already exists, file not renamed"
               else
                       echo "Move $file to $target_name"
                       mv "$file" "$target_name"
                 fi
               fi
       done
done ````
`````

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

- You've got some duplicates in `arrayGrep`
- You have some quoting issues: `$1` in the grep and sed commands must be protected from the shell
- some of the disallowed characters, even if quoted to protect from the shell, could be mis-parsed by grep as meta-characters
- You loop rather a lot when all substitutions could happen simultaneously
- `for file in $(find ...)` has to read the entire list into memory, which might be problematic for large lists. It also breaks with some filenames due to word-splitting. Piping into read is better
- find can do path filtering without grep (at least for this set of disallowed characters)
- `sed` is fine to use but `tr` is a little neater

A possible rewrite is:

```
badchars='?*,#;:&@+<>%$~'

find . -name "*[$badchars]*" | while read -r file
do
    target_name=$(echo "$file" | tr "$badchars" - )
    if [ "$file" != "$target_name" ]; then
        if [ -e $target_name ]; then
            echo "WARNING: $target_name already exists, file not renamed"
        else
            echo "Move $file to $target_name"
            mv "$file" "$target_name"
        fi
    fi
done
```

If using bash, you can even do parameter expansion directly,
although you have to embed the list:

```
    target_name="${file//[?*,#;:&@+<>%$~]/-}"
```

---

**an enhancement idea**

If you choose a suitable character (eg. `=`), you can rename filenames reversibly (but only if the length of the new name wouldn't exceed the maximum allowed length for a filename). One possible algorithm:

1. replace all `=` in the filename with `=3D`
2. replace all the other disallowed characters with `=hh` where `hh` is the appropriate ASCII code in hex

You can reverse the renaming by:

1. replace all `=hh` (except `=3D`) with the character corresponding to ASCII code `hh`
2. replace all `=3D` with `=`